# WFFM Data Manipulation before Export

Tags: wffm

We are having issues on WFFM in 8.1.

Values for the checboxlist field are stored in xdb and form reports in some format like follows.

```
<item>US</item><item>UK</item><item>Australia</item>.
```

Can we store values as comma separated values or any other way. In simple, can we modify the values before exporting?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the values during exporting. To do this, please modify the following classes and modify the output as per your requirements.

Export to XML -

```
Sitecore.WFFM.Services.Pipelines.ExportToXml.ExportFormDataToXml, Sitecore.WFFM.Services
```

Export to Excel -

```
Sitecore.WFFM.Services.Pipelines.ExportToExcel.ExportFormDataToExcel, Sitecore.WFFM.Services
```

The above mentioned services can be configured in `Website\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.WFFM.Services.config`

Also please don't change the values in xDB as it is not best practice.